# How can I shift position of an element in a series on click?

Tags: jquery

I have container in the left include 3 divs with 3 button and I have an empty container in the right. I also have a div which includes product number 0 and total price 0.

How can I move one div to the right when I press its button and the product number increase 1, total price increase 200 and so on with the other divs, and when I press again the button the div returns to its original location and product number, total price return 0?

```js
var $counter = 1;
var x = 200;
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function(event) {
    if ($('.child').hasClass('child')) {
      $('.child ').toggleClass('right');
      $('button').text('sell');
    }
    var z = setInterval(function() {
      $('.s1').text($counter)
      $('.s2').text(x)
      if ($counter < x) {
        clearInterval(z);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.parent {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 700px;
  width: 1500px;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: gray;
  /*position: relative;*/
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container .child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container div img {
  width: 200px;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.middle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 520px;
  position: absolute;
}

.middle p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  float: right;
  transform: translateX(1300px);
  transition: 3s;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.left {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  transform: translateX(-1300px);
  transition: 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">
      <img src="imgs/house2.jpg">
      <button>Buy</button>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <img src="imgs/house2.jpg">
      <button>Buy</button>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <img src="imgs/house2.jpg">
      <button>Buy</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <p> product Number <span class="s1">  0</span> </p>
    <p> Total price <span class="s2"> 0</span></p>

  </div>
  <div class="container2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would look into [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and use the ordering feature. Otherwise you'll need to remove the element and append it in a new position. You probably can't do it very easily with CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```js
var x = 200;

$(function() {
  $('button').click(function(event) {
    let currentProductsNum = $('.s1').text();
    let totalPrice = $('.s2').text();
    
    // check if parent has .child class and also check if parent has class right
    if ($(this).closest('.child') && !$(this).closest('.child').is('.right')) {
      $(this).closest('.child').toggleClass('right');
      $(this).text('sell');
      $('.s1').text(++currentProductsNum); // increment product number
      $('.s2').text(parseInt(parseInt(totalPrice) + x)); // increment total price
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.child').toggleClass('right');
      $(this).text('Buy');
      $('.s1').text(--currentProductsNum);
      $('.s2').text(parseInt(parseInt(totalPrice) - x));
    }
    
    /*var z = setInterval(function() {
      $('.s1').text($counter)
      $('.s2').text(x)
      if ($counter < x) {
        clearInterval(z);
      }
    })*/
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.parent {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 700px;
  width: 1500px;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: gray;
  /*position: relative;*/
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container .child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container div img {
  width: 200px;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.middle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 520px;
  position: absolute;
}

.middle p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  float: right;
  transform: translateX(1300px);
  transition: 3s;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.left {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  transform: translateX(-1300px);
  transition: 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">
      <img src="imgs/house2.jpg">
      <button>Buy</button>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <img src="imgs/house2.jpg">
      <button>Buy</button>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <img src="imgs/house2.jpg">
      <button>Buy</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <p> product Number <span class="s1">0</span> </p>
    <p> Total price <span class="s2">0</span></p>

  </div>
  <div class="container2">

  </div>
</div>
```